# Why is matlab stretching my image? (image v. imagesc v. imshow)

Tags: image, matlab

I have a 250x250px image. When I call image or imagesc, the image is stretched to be much taller than it is wide. When I call imshow, this is not the case. Why are the first two stretching it to be vertically stretched?

Comment: Do you really want to know why MATLAB behaves as it is or do you want to know how to fix this?

Comment: `imshow` is a high-level function. `image` is a more generic low-level function that doesn't necessarily render the pixels as square. Try `axis image`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form of the function:

```
image(x,y,C)
```

or

```
imagesc(x,y,C)
```

More details here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html?searchHighlight=image
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html?refresh=true

Comment: That's not what is being asked. Read the question more carefully.  This form of `image` / `imagesc` redefines the horizontal and vertical coordinates for display.  This does not address the "stretching" the OP is experiencing.